# asp.net only inserts 255 characters into the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, insert

I am doing a project and I started to test a part of it. I realize that I have a small problem but cannot understand it. I am trying to insert some data to database, there is a column which is nvarchar(4000). But whenever I try to insert any length of string, It only inserts 255 chars.  Why does it take only 255 characters?

here is my code,

```
dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("New_Post");
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "PostHeader", DbType.String, txt_post_header.Text.Trim());
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "PostBody", DbType.String, txt_post_body.Text.Trim());
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "UserId", DbType.Guid, new Guid(Session["SessionUserID"].ToString()));
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "PollDescription", DbType.String, txt_poll.Text);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "CityId", DbType.Int16, 1);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "SpecialtyID", DbType.Int16, Convert.ToInt16(Session["SessionSpecialityId"].ToString()));
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
```

Comment: What's the type of the parameters of stored procedure New_Post? nvarchar(4000) too? (moreover...what does it do inside?)

Comment: Does the **stored procedure** possibly limit the parameter to 255 chars? Otherwise: can you **specify a length** for your `DbType.String` parameters using `db.AddInParameter(...)` - maybe that default to 255 unless you specify otherwise....

Comment: you are the man :) thank you very much. In the Procdure, ıt was declared 255.

Comment: Are you using the Data Access Application Block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not declaring the parameter with a limit, the only 2 options you have is that the database field have 256 as limit or the Parameter in your stored Procedure, check that and you should fix your problem.